# Finding a matrix that projects (x, y, z) onto the line through (1, 2, 2)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Find a matrix $P_1$ that projects $(x, y, z)$ onto the line through $(1, 2, 2)$.

I am unsure how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: Do you want an _orthogonal_ projection? There is an infinite number of projections onto a line otherwise. If so, do you know how to compute this without using matrices?

Comment: What is **the** line through $(1,2,2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\dfrac{(x,y,z)\cdot (1,2,2)}9(1,2,2)=\dfrac{x+2y+2z}9(1,2,2)$ would be the projection.

Now apply to the standard basis:

$(1,0,0)\to(\dfrac19,\dfrac29,\dfrac29) $  etc.  to get the columns.

How about:  $\dfrac19\begin{pmatrix} 1&2&2\\2&4&4\\2&4&4\end{pmatrix}$?